# Doubts about require and require-dev of Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm setting a composer-installable repository. I read the Composer documentation and I setup my repository with success following the instructions. What I understood of the difference between `require` and `require-dev` was that the `require-dev` is for declare dependencies that aren't mandatory for that the repository works properly.

However, I watched the composer.json of some libraries on Github, like [Zend Form](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/composer.json) and [Respect Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/composer.json), and, on these two repositories, there are packages that are required to that these repositories works properly and are listed in `require-dev`. For example, the `egulias/email-validator` dependency is listed in `require-dev` in Respect Validation, but on [this file](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Rules/Email.php), this dependency is required in order that Email Validator works. So, why this dependency isn't listed in `require`?

The same happens with `zendframework/zend-captcha`, required for that the [Captcha element](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element/Captcha.php) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this dependency is required in order that Email Validator works.

It isn't. You can see that `Respect\Validation\Rules\Email` has an optional dependency to `Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator`. If the `egulias/email-validator` is provided, then the class will [use it](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Rules/Email.php#L37), otherwise it will fallback to [filter_var](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/library/Rules/Email.php#L40). The class will works either way. What the package can do is [suggest](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/composer.json#L28) you to install it.

Comment: This is true. But and for Zend Captcha? I watched the code and I don't see a way of use it without use an element of Zend\Captcha component. See the setCaptcha method. If I provide an array or something that implements Traversable interface, it use a Factory of Zend\Captcha component. The other option is provide something that implements the AdapterInterface of Zend\Captcha component...

Comment: It's the same for `Zend\Form\Element\Captcha`. The documentation of the `setCaptcha` method require `zend-captcha`, but that not imply that `zend-form` has a dependency to `zend-captcha`. If _your_ application use `setCaptcha`, then it's your responsibility to pass some instance of `ZendCaptcha\AdapterInterface`, and to do that you need to install that package. Also, the good majority of the people that choose to use `zendframework/zend-form` may not use the Captcha. You really don't want install dependency that you don't use anyway.

Comment: What I'm say is that `zend-form` doesn't use `zend-captcha` directly. You need to create some object with the `zend-captcha` package in your application, and then you pass that object to the component of `zend-form` , that's able to manage it. But that does not mean that `zend-form` require `zend-captcha`. Your application does.